# Can not load CSS file

Tags: html, css, node.js, nginx

Start working with node.js and nginx, previously did not work with web servers at all.
For configure server used some manuals.
Seems to have done everything right, but faced with a problem the server does not load css files

My nginx directory set up is like this :

```
/
index.html
css/
   /*css files*/
images/
   /*image files*/
js/
  /*js files*/
```

My index file is like this :

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />

    <!-- navbar -->  
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top ">  
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Головна</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">  
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-4">
 <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" data-value="about" href="#">Оновлення</a>        </li>  
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link " data-value="portfolio"href="#">Інсталяційні пакети</a>    
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item"> 
    <a class="nav-link " data-value="blog" href="#">Довідка</a>         </li>    
</ul> 
</div></nav>
</head>
<header class="header">   
</header>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

My nodejs directory set up is like this:

```
/
server.js
package.json
node_modeles/
```

My node.js is like this :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8000

app.get('/', function(req, res){ res.sendFile('/var/www/nginx/index.html')});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

My nginx server setup:

```
server {
        charset utf-8;
        listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.95.147;
        root /var/www/nodejs;
        index index.html;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        error_page 400 401 402 403 404 /40x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /var/www/errors;
        }
 location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.95.147:8000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connetction 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
        location /nginx/ {
                root /var/www/;
                autoindex off;

        }
}
```

Comment: Try using `href="/css/bootstrap.css"`

Comment: thanks for answer.
try it, but still not working

Comment: can you access your css file directly through URL?

Comment: no, i cant get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this in your **app.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
```

Comment: add answer with problem